# Drag & Drop Image and mantain its thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a small drag and drop gallery. I have my small gallery of images and I want to drag them and drop then in another specific div. Currently the images thumnail gets lost at the moment of the drop.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var cpydata = document.getElementById(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(cpydata);
}
```

This makes a lot of sense, because I'm not saving no reference of the object that was drag. I have a demo showing this effect. [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/belexa/4/edit?js,output)

After this I thought, that if I clone the object I was dragging and append it to the image gallery this will work, but it doesn't. It only works the first time I drag, and the image changes of position. After the second time it stops working. After the first time **data** isn't returning me the *drag1* as it did the first time, but returns me the image. Not sure why it does this. Here it's a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/belexa/3/edit?js,output).

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var cpydata = document.getElementById(data);
    cpydataElement = cpydata.cloneNode(true);
    var columnId = document.getElementById("column");
    cpydata.removeAttribute("id"); 
    ev.target.appendChild(cpydata);
    columnId.innerHTML = columnId.innerHTML + cpydataElement.outerHTML ; 
}
```

The HTML is this one.

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

  <div id="column">  
    <img id="drag1" src="http://collectionofpicture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/high-resolution-landscape-wallpaper-69.jpg" draggable="true" class="test">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://collectionofpicture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/3d-landscape-wallpaper-131.jpg" draggable="true" class="test">
    <img id="drag3" src="http://collectionofpicture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/natural-landscape-wallpaper-91.jpg" draggable="true" class="test">
  </div>
```

I have tried to get a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=drag%20and%20drop%20images%20thumbnail), but haven't found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I was assigning bad the clone img.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var cpydata = document.getElementById(data);
    cpydataElement = cpydata.cloneNode(true);
    var columnId = document.getElementById("column");
    cpydataElement.removeAttribute("id"); 
    ev.target.appendChild(cpydataElement);
}
```

Functional [Demo](http://jsbin.com/belexa/6)